# Calculating watt usage from an input/output electronics spec for step-down transformer's minimum watt limit

Tags: transformer, watts, power-consumption, step-down

I'm trying to calculate the minimum watt limit needed for a step-down transformer that convert 220 V to 120V from source (220V) to 125V smart plug then to an electronic appliance with the following spec.

```
Input 100-240V AC~0.33A
Output 5V=2A
```

I calculate the maximum watt usage of input to be at 79.2 Watt (`240V*0.33A`) and output to be at 10 Watt (`5V*2A`).

Does this means that the step-down transformer should support at least 79.2 Watt in which 100 Watt spec should be fine?

Comment: If you are trying to supply power to a device that asks that its input is between 100 and 240 V, then you do not need a step down transformer from a 220 V supply. ???

Comment: XY problem. Why would you need a transformer at all? What’s your mains voltage where you live?

Comment: @emrys57  (Edited the question) The reason I need the transformer is because I need to use a smart plug which only support 125V input in which the electronic appliance is connected to. I added the additional information to the question.

Comment: @winny I update the question which required a smart plug which only support 125V input. The main voltage from where I live is 220V.

Comment: Get a smart plug for your mains voltage. Everything else is asking for problems.

Comment: Are you trying to install a 125V [smart] outlet in the wall, powered by a transformer from your 220V mains? That's not safe. Transformers should not be enclosed in residential walls, I don't know of any electric code which allows that.

Comment: @John I'm trying to use a step-down transformer which have an input a source of 220V and a 120V output. The connect the smart plug 125V input to the transformer's 120V output. Then plug the appliance to the smart plug output.

Comment: Please don’t. Get a new smart plug.

Comment: how did you get a 120V smart plug in a 240V country - did you order the wrong smart plug? did you bring it overseas with you?